# How to set log level for Payara Micro

Tags: payara-micro

I have a project where I need to run javaee7 microservice with payara micro.
For this reason, I build a payara uber jar with maven, so I can just run it as

```
java -jar MicroService.jar
```

(http://blog.payara.fish/creating-uber-jar-with-payara-micro )

How can I set the logging level for payara, so that only warnings and errors are displayed, without INFO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify an alternative `logging.properties` file using `--logProperties` option followed by path to the file. This is not documented in the official documentation, but you can get a brief info about it when you execute `java -jar payara-micro.jar --help`.

You can find a template `logging.properties` file when you create a domain directory by running a plain Payara Micro with the `--rootDir` argument - it will copy all documentation from the JAR file into the specified folder (the folder must exist - might be empty). You can find `logging.properties` in `config/logging.properties`, take it, edit it, and pass it to Payara Micro using the `--logProperties` argument.

If you want to specify log levels within the uber JAR, without adding a separate `logging.properties` file, you may configure the logging either by running appropriate [asadmin commands from within your application](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/content/documentation/payara-micro/asadmin.html) or directly setting log level on JUL loggers using [LogManager API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).

Comment: Resurrecting this a bit, it [seems that the format in that case is not the one that Payara Micro uses by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534984/how-does-payara-micro-determine-its-logging-format-it-differs-from-that-specifi).  How, using this approach, can I get the same format as that used by Payara Micro when it starts up without arguments?