# How does Payara Micro determine its logging format (it differs from that specified by default logging.properties)?

Tags: payara, payara-micro

Here is an example of running Payara Micro 172 from the command line.  Note its log format:

```
LANELSON$ java -jar ~/Downloads/payara-micro-4.1.2.172.jar 
[2017-08-06T10:47:56.814-0700] [] [INFO] [] 
[fish.payara.micro.boot.runtime.PayaraMicroRuntimeBuilder] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1502041676814] [levelValue: 800] Built Payara Micro Runtime
```

OK, that's fine.

I want to change some log levels.  I understand I can add `--logProperties someLogging.properties` and it will pick up the standard Java logging properties from there.  Obviously I'd like to *add* to whatever Payara Micro does, so first I'm going to run it with the `--rootdir` argument so that its `logging.properties` is generated for me (so I can crib from it):

```
LANELSON$ java -jar ~/Downloads/payara-micro-4.1.2.172.jar --rootdir crap
[2017-08-06T10:50:07.112-0700] [] [INFO] [] 
[fish.payara.micro.boot.runtime.PayaraMicroRuntimeBuilder] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1502041807112] [levelValue: 800] Built Payara Micro Runtime
```

Now when I look in `crap/config`, I see `logging.properties`, which looks, in part, like this:

```
LANELSON$ cat crap/config/logging.properties 
#Payara Micro Logging Properties File

## Handlers
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

…and so on.  That's fine.  So now I am going to grab that `logging.properties` and add some levels to it (but not otherwise change it; specifically, I'm going to use the formatters and handlers in it as is).  Then I'm going to remove everything else in that `crap` directory, and go back to launching Payara Micro *without* the `--rootdir` argument, but this time with the `--logProperties` argument:

```
LANELSON$ java -jar ~/Downloads/payara-micro-4.1.2.172.jar --logProperties crap/config/logging.properties
Aug 06, 2017 10:54:08 AM fish.payara.micro.boot.runtime.PayaraMicroRuntimeBuilder build
INFO: Built Payara Micro Runtime
```

Note that the formatting has changed.  That tells me that the `logging.properties` that is generated for you when you use the `--rootdir` argument is *not* the same as the effective one used internally by Payara Micro when it starts up.

So: how does Payara Micro determine what its logging settings are when it starts up without any other arguments?  How can I use *those* logging properties?  Am I being bitten by [issue #1672](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1672)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you are hitting https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1672 and this will resolved in Payara 173 via PR https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/1835

Comment: I still see the same problem using payara micro 174.